# Xstream stops writing to file when not finished

Tags: java, xml

I have written some code to generate passwords for users that were written to sql before. Then I wanted to write each user with username and password to xml. The code seems to work fine except at around 200th user it suddenly stops halfway through xml tag and ends, which is pretty weird. I'm using Xstream as my library. The Arraylist has like 215 users.

I tried StaxDriver and DomDriver. The Stax Driver result was same as empty Xstream constructor, but Dom was even worse.

```
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.alias("Zakaznici", ListZakazniku.class);

        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Zakaznici.xml");
            out.write(xstream.toXML(ListZakazniku.zakaznici));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

```
public class ListZakazniku {
    public static ArrayList<Zakaznik> zakaznici = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListZakazniku(){
        zakaznici= new ArrayList<Zakaznik>();
    }

    public void setZakaznici(ArrayList<Zakaznik> zakaznik){
        this.zakaznici.clear();
        this.zakaznici = zakaznik;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Zakaznik> getZakaznici() {
        return zakaznici;
    }

    public void add(Zakaznik elbow){
        zakaznici.add(elbow);
    }
```

and Zakaznik is pretty basic object with username, password, id....

the cut was like

```
</Zakaznik>
<Zaka
```

I don't know what's wrong with it. Im looking forward to any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list should not be static, also slightly modified your printing code. An approach like this will work fine:

```
@XStreamAlias("listZakazniku")
public class ListZakazniku {

    private List<Zakaznik> zakaznicis;

    public ListZakazniku() {
        zakaznicis = new ArrayList<Zakaznik>();
    }

    public void add(Zakaznik user) {
        zakaznicis.add(user);
    }


    @XStreamAlias("zakaznik")
    private static class Zakaznik {
        private String user;
        private String pwd;
        public Zakaznik(String user, String pwd) {
            this.user = user;
            this.pwd = pwd;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.processAnnotations(ListZakazniku.class);
        ListZakazniku ll = new ListZakazniku();
        ll.add(new Zakaznik("user1", "pwd1"));
        ll.add(new Zakaznik("user2", "pwd2"));
        try {
            try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Zakaznici.xml")) {
                out.println(xstream.toXML(ll));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<listZakazniku>
  <zakaznicis>
    <zakaznik>
      <user>user1</user>
      <pwd>pwd1</pwd>
    </zakaznik>
    <zakaznik>
      <user>user2</user>
      <pwd>pwd2</pwd>
    </zakaznik>
  </zakaznicis>
</listZakazniku>
```

Don't forget the processAnnotations-call for each annotated class! (also, your Zakaznik is not an internal static class I guess like in my example above, this was just to squeeze in the complete code..)

Comment: Thaks a lot, it really helped me out :)